# Disable escape in Zend Form Element Submit

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I can't disable escaping in a Zend_Form_Element_Submit, so when the label has special characters it won't display it's value..

This is my actual Zend Form piece of code:

```
$this->submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$this->submit->setLabel('Iniciar Sesión');
$this->submit->setIgnore(true);
$this->addElement($this->submit);
```

I've tried `$this->submit->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape', false);` but I obtain an "non-object" error (maybe submit isn't using the "Label" Decorator)..

I've also tried as suggested `$this->submit->setAttrib('escape', false);` but no text will be shown either.. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as doing this:

`$element->addDecorator('Label', аrray('escape'=>false));`

Or see `setEscape()`.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html

Regarding failure to retrieve named decorator...  Try `getDecorators()`  Do you see 'label' in the results?

Comment: I did miss in first reading this that we are talking about a button, not an element label.  Still, element's decorator may be using `htmlentities` defaulting to ISO-8599-1 so my answer might still apply.  Obviously also make sure that doctype, encoding, content-type, etc are all set to UTF-8.

Comment: Label Decorator does not know setEscape, `$form->getElement($elemName)->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);` does the trick though. I needed this to include a `<a href=` in a label.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Label decorator for submit form element by default (this is why you get the error).
The `$this->submit->setLabel('Iniciar Sesión');` value goes to Zend_View_Helper_FormSubmit, which always does escaping and uses the label as a value.

Answer (score 1):

The helper used by the Submit element escapes by default. Unlike with the label decorator, submit labels are included in a HTML attribute so they need to be escaped.

Your label - Iniciar Sesión - is a perfectly valid UTF-8 string, so the escaped version of it will be the same. If your label is not appearing then something else is going wrong. I'd guess that your page is being served using a charset that doesn't match what Zend View is using (UTF-8 by default).

View the page source to see what actually gets output - that might give you some more clues. Alternatively if the page this form is on is public, if you can provide a URL we might be able to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. In my instance, I added both a label and a description to a text field element. This line of code allowed me to turn off the html escaping for the description attached to that field element:

```
$form->getElement('txtUPC')->getDecorator('description')->setOption('escape', false);
```

In my testing, the `setEscape()` was not recognized by the form elements or their decorators.